# Find a Directory somewhere in Subdirectories

Tags: vb.net, file, directory, find

I want to find a directory somewhere among a lot of subdirectories using VB.NET.  I have the path of the parent directory (`D:\`) and I have the name of the subdirectory (`X`) and I want to find this directory in any of the subdirectories of `D:\`.  In `D:\` I have 3 subdirectories (`A`, `B`, and `C`) and I want to find `X` (the name of the directory) inside `A,`B`or`C`.  Is it possible to do that with VB.NET?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using the [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462.aspx) method, like this:

```
For Each i As String In Directory.EnumerateDirectories("D:\", "X", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Console.WriteLine("Matching Directory: " & i)
Next
```

Please note that there may be multiple matches.  Also, be aware that if the directory tree is very large, it may take a long time for the method to find all of the matches.  The key to that working for you is the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` option.  By passing `AllDirectories`, that causes the method to search the entire directory tree below `"D:\"`.  If you omitted that parameter, or passed `TopDirectoryOnly`, it would only look at the directories that are directly children of `"D:\"`.  It would not search through all of the descendants.

If you just want to get an array of all the matching directories, you can alternatively use the [`Directory.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314.aspx) method:

```
Dim matches() As String = Directory.GetDirectories("D:\", "X", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
If matches.Length > 0 Then
    Console.WriteLine("First match: " & matches(0))
End If
```

The advantage of the `EnumerateDirectories` method, though, is that, if you only care about the first match, you can exit the loop after processing the first match and skip searching the rest of the directory tree.  From the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462.aspx):

> The EnumerateDirectories and GetDirectories methods differ as follows: When you use EnumerateDirectories, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetDirectories, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, EnumerateDirectories can be more efficient.

For instance, if you really only cared about the first match, it would be more efficient to do this:

```
For Each i As String In Directory.EnumerateDirectories("D:\", "X", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Console.WriteLine("First match: " & i)
    Exit For
Next
```

Or with LINQ:

```
Dim firstMatch As String = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("D:\", "X", SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault()
If firstMatch IsNot Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine(firstMatch)
End If
```

Comment: Well you post got pretty thorough since last time I checked :) I'd give you +1 again if I could.

Comment: @user3432981 No problem.  If this answered your question, you should click the checkbox to mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

it will help you in getting all the directories in the specified path. Regarding the second argument that is the "pattern" try and check pattern as "" and hopefully should return and array of all directories and subdirectories

Then you can just compare/search for the file name in the returned array list using simple for loop and display the result which will show where the file is located